# MSSql login is sometimes not created

Tags: sql-server, docker, powershell

I'm creating a script which starts an MSSQL service in Docker and after a short delay creates databases and user to access those database. It often works fine but sometimes it doesn't create a login (but still creates databases).
My DockerFile contains this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest

USER root
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/Scripts/Docker/run-initialization.sh

ENV MSSQL_PASSWORD Pass1234
ENV SA_PASSWORD Pass1234
ENV ACCEPT_EULA Y
ENV MSSQL_PID Express

CMD /bin/bash ./entrypoint.sh
```

entrypoint.sh:
`/usr/src/app/Scripts/Docker/run-initialization.sh & /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr`

run-initialization.sh:

```
sleep 30s
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P $MSSQL_PASSWORD -d master -i /usr/src/app/Scripts/Database/create-local-databases.sql
```

(sleep is suggested by a lot of articles and microsoft itself as an approach for applying some scripts after mssql server startup)

And finally create-local-databases contains this:

```
CREATE DATABASE [test];
GO
CREATE DATABASE [test2];
GO
CREATE LOGIN TestUser WITH PASSWORD = 'Pass1234';
GO
CREATE USER TestUser FOR LOGIN TestUser;
GO
ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER [TestUser];
```

Inside docker container I find these logs:

```
2021-10-05 11:41:55.78 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2021-10-05 11:41:55.78 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'test'. [CLIENT: 172.17.0.1]
2021-10-05 11:42:05.88 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2021-10-05 11:42:05.88 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'test'. [CLIENT: 172.17.0.1]
2021-10-05 11:42:06.30 spid74      [5]. Feature Status: PVS: 0. CTR: 0. ConcurrentPFSUpdate: 1.
2021-10-05 11:42:06.30 spid74      Starting up database 'test'.
2021-10-05 11:42:06.35 spid74      Parallel redo is started for database 'test' with worker pool size [4].
2021-10-05 11:42:06.38 spid74      Parallel redo is shutdown for database 'test' with worker pool size [4].
2021-10-05 11:42:06.56 spid74      Setting database option READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT to ON for database 'test'.
2021-10-05 11:42:06.71 spid74      [5]. Feature Status: PVS: 0. CTR: 0. ConcurrentPFSUpdate: 1.
2021-10-05 11:42:06.71 spid74      Starting up database 'test'.
2021-10-05 11:42:06.77 spid74      Parallel redo is started for database 'test' with worker pool size [4].
2021-10-05 11:42:06.80 spid74      Parallel redo is shutdown for database 'test' with worker pool size [4].
2021-10-05 11:42:13.13 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2021-10-05 11:42:13.13 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'test2'. [CLIENT: 172.17.0.1]
2021-10-05 11:42:23.19 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2021-10-05 11:42:23.19 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'test2'. [CLIENT: 172.17.0.1]
2021-10-05 11:42:23.53 spid74      [6]. Feature Status: PVS: 0. CTR: 0. ConcurrentPFSUpdate: 1.
2021-10-05 11:42:23.53 spid74      Starting up database 'test2'.
2021-10-05 11:42:23.58 spid74      Parallel redo is started for database 'test2' with worker pool size [4].
2021-10-05 11:42:23.61 spid74      Parallel redo is shutdown for database 'test2' with worker pool size [4].
2021-10-05 11:42:23.80 spid74      Setting database option READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT to ON for database 'test2'.
2021-10-05 11:42:23.94 spid74      [6]. Feature Status: PVS: 0. CTR: 0. ConcurrentPFSUpdate: 1.
2021-10-05 11:42:23.95 spid74      Starting up database 'test2'.
2021-10-05 11:42:24.00 spid74      Parallel redo is started for database 'test2' with worker pool size [4].
2021-10-05 11:42:24.04 spid74      Parallel redo is shutdown for database 'test2' with worker pool size [4].
```

I see the authorization error at the very top but I don't understand why if authorization is not done databases are created as normal and why authorization doesn't work some times but it does in others. My only consideration is that login creation for some reason happens before the base database (or smth like it) start and dbs creation happen after. But they are written in another order.  Also if I login into my local dbs after they are created and copy-paste login creation part of the script above it works perfectly. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with docker... Is this instance newly created each time or is it shut down and restarted? If if is shutdown, unless those databases are dropped, it will fail?

Comment: @SEarle1986 this commands basically drop the existing container and create a new one. So every time they start new sql server and create new dbs.